# Let $M_1$ be compact, then $<C(M_1, M_2), \tau>$ is complete iff $M_2$ is complete

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Here is the full question.

> Let $M_1$ be compact. Let $<C(M_1, M_2), \tau>$ denote the metric space of all continuous functions between $M_1$ and $M_2$ endowed with the $\tau$ metric, which is:
>   $$\tau(f,g)=\max\{d_2(f(x),g(x)), \forall x \in M_1\}
> $$
>   Show that $M_2$ complete $\iff$ $<C(M_1, M_2), \tau>$ is complete.

Intuitively, I see that if there are no gaps in the space of continuous functions, then $M_2$ must also have no gaps, and vice versa. But how do I show these ideas rigorously and bring the compactness of $M_1$ into the picture?

Answer (score 1):

The compactness of $M_1$ is only necessary in order for the metric to be well-defined.

Okay, so assume that $M_2$ is complete and let $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a Cauchy sequence of continuous functions. Then, for every $x\in M_1$, we have $d_2(f_n(x),f_m(x))\leq \tau(f_n,f_m),$ implying that $(f_n(x))_{n\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy in $M_2$. Since $M_2$ is complete, we can define $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$.

Now, by continuity of $d_2$, for any $x$, we have $d_2(f_n(x),f(x))=\lim_{m\to\infty} d_2(f_n(x),f_m(x))\leq \sup_{m\geq n} d_2(f_n,f_m).$ Since $x$ was arbitrary, this implies that $\tau(f_n,f)\leq \sup_{m\geq n} d_2(f_n,f_m).$ Since $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy, we conclude that $f$ is, in fact the uniform limit of $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. As uniform limits of continuous functions are continuous, $f$ is continuous, and $C(M_1,M_2)$ is complete.

Conversely, if $C(M_1,M_2)$ is complete, let $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be Cauchy in $M_2$ and define $f_n(x)=y_n$ for all $x$. Then, clearly $\tau(f_n,f_m)=d_2(y_n,y_m)$, implying that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy. Since $C(M_1,M_2)$ is completely, there exists some $f:=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n$. Since uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence, $f$ must be constantly equal to some $y\in M_2$. It's now obvious that $y=\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n$.